# Getting a select's option value in MVC5

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-5

This is the `<select>`, and I want to get the value of an `<option>` element:

```
<select>
    <option value="ln">lion</option>
    <option value="cn">Cow</option>
    <option value="sn">Snake</option>
    <option value="ki">Kiwi</option>
</select>
```

In the Controller, I'm trying to use `collection.Get` to get the value but it keeps failing:

```
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection collection){
    ViewBag.Species = collection.Get("Species");
}
```

Comment: You need a name attribute in the select `<select name="Species">` so it will post back (but why are your doing all this manually if your using MVC?)

Comment: @StephenMuecke That's the way we are getting taught

Comment: Get a new teacher :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Better than that i should apply at a new Uni lol